# passage of several Parameters for the same screen in WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Good evening everyone

I'm trying to pass two objects at the same screen over the error to pass the second. I would like to know how to treat this receipt on my main screen.

I will try to give an example below:

first send an object parameter for the screen client

```
private void btTelaPedido (object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
Customer customer = new Customer ();
    customer.custid = Convert.ToInt32 (tbCodCliente.Text);
    cliente.razao = tbNomeCliente.Text;

    Frame.Navigate (typeof (pedidoTelaCadastro), client);
```

}

then go to another screen and send another object

```
private void listaProduto_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            Product produtoEscolhido = (sender the ListView) .SelectedItem the product;
            Frame.Navigate (typeof (pedidoTelaCadastro), produtoEscolhido);
        }
```

and that is, to receive code on the main screen.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo (NavigationEventArgs e) {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo (e);

 ClienteRecebido customer = (customer) e.Parameter;
                tbIdCliente.Text = Convert.ToString (clienteRecebido.idCliente);
                tbCliente.Text = clienteRecebido.razao;
                tbDataPedido.Text = "01/01/2015";

            ProdutoRecebido product = (Product) e.Parameter;
            tbProduto.Text = Convert.ToString (produtoRecebido.descricao);

        }
```

I wonder how he treats

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    Customer clienteRecebido =  e.Parameter as Customer;
    if(clienteRecebido !=null)
    {
        tbIdCliente.Text = Convert.ToString (clienteRecebido.idCliente);
        tbCliente.Text = clienteRecebido.razao;
        tbDataPedido.Text = "01/01/2015";
    }
    else
    {
        ProdutoRecebido product = (Product) e.Parameter;
        tbProduto.Text = Convert.ToString (produtoRecebido.descricao);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Clarice what u gave me did not work because it conflicted every time I tried to include a product just acahando otherwise.

Comment: if (e.Parameter.GetType() == typeof(Cliente)){
            Cliente clienteRecebido = (Cliente)e.Parameter;
            }
            else if (e.Parameter.GetType() == typeof(Produto)) { 
            Produto produtoRecebido = (Produto)e.Parameter;
           
            }